# How to filter by dynamic object properties in Angularfire

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have a model like below in Angular + AngularFire + Firestore project

```
export interface Game {
    id: string;
    ... some other properties
    players: Array<{
       userId: string;
       name: string;
       picture: string;
    }>;
    playerIds: { [userId: string]: boolean };
}
```

and data look like this

[image]

Now I want to query all records where a specific userId is one of the players.

since I want to only filter by `userId` (not whole player object), I can not use `array-contain`, so I added a `playerIds` property which is a map object.

and my code is like

```
    this.collection((ref) => ref.where(`playerIds.${user.id}`, '==', true).where(`status`, '!=', GameStatus.Started)).valueChanges(),
```

Then it asked me to create an index for this query. The issue is the index is very specific for that user, and it's included that specific user id.

[image]

In my other project using firebase in nodejs I have done same thing over and over, but seems in AngularFire it's different.

I know if I change it to array of userIds I can query by `array-contains`, my question is why this is not working and how make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `playerIds` field you have in your screenshot is not an array, but a map with the keys `bTr2...` and `lnm4...` and the values being `true`. Unfortunately you'll need a separate index for each field in that map.

To be able to use a single index, turn the `playerIds` field into an actual array:

```
playerIds: ["bTr2...", "lnm4..."]
```

With this structure, you:

- Only need a single index, on the `playerIds` field.
- Can query with `array-contains`.
- Can add items to the array with `arrayUnion`.
- Remove items from the array with `arrayRemove`.

Also see the documentation on [updating elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: Thanks for answer, although your solution will work, but I just figured out the root cause of the issue and it started working, the issue was combination of `!=` filter for status, when I coinicdentally removed that, it started working. so I moved that status filter to rxjs map

Comment: Good to hear that you figured it out @Reza. .  It might be worth posting that (with code) as a self-answer, so others are more likely to see it in the future.

Comment: I marked your answer and correct solution, since if index is needed seems there is no way

Answer (score 0):

Although Frank van Puffelen solution is working, but I figured it out what was wrong.

Seems if we have multiple `where` or `order` that needs index the problem is inevitable. In my case I found out I should have used `==` instead of `!=` in second `where`, when I changed that, it didn't need any index and I was able to query like that

```
ref.where(`playerIds.${user.id}`, '==', true).where(`status`, '==', GameStatus.Started)
```